# How to deduct in group by query in sum in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have query like this ::

```
SELECT account.AccountNumber, account.NAME, Sum(agro.price * agro.qty) AS Expr1
FROM ((account
INNER JOIN data ON account.AccountNumber = data.acno)
INNER JOIN agro ON agro.BillNo = data.BillNo)
WHERE data.db='true'
GROUP BY account.AccountNumber, account.NAME;
```

I want to deduct another groupby query output in to **Sum(agro.price * agro.qty)** this
the another group by query is **SELECT Sum(rs),acno
FROM jma group by acno;**
i want to deduct Sum(agro.price * agro.qty)-Sum(rs) how its work please help me solve this

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot add or subtract from summed data.  You need to get to the record level- what specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly the following query may work for you:

```
SELECT subQ.AccountNumber, subQ.NAME, (subQ.subSum - jmaSum.jSum) AS FinalSum
FROM 
(
  SELECT a.AccountNumber, a.NAME, Sum(ag.price * ag.qty) AS subSum
  FROM (account AS a
    INNER JOIN data AS d ON a.AccountNumber = d.acno)
    INNER JOIN agro AS ag ON ag.BillNo = d.BillNo
  WHERE d.db = 'true'
  GROUP BY a.AccountNumber, a.NAME
) AS subQ
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT Sum(j.rs) AS jSum, j.acno 
  FROM jma AS j
  GROUP BY j.acno
) AS jmaSum ON subQ.AccountNumber = jmaSum.acno
```